# pass an file into antfile when using ANT task

Tags: java, xml, ant

For example, I have two build.xml: build.xml and subbuild.xml. In the build.xml, it will use an ant task to call and run the subbuild.xml like this:

```
<target name="antCall1" >
    <ant antfile="${basedir}/cache/subBuildTarget/subbuild.xml" />
</target>
```

My question is like this: I have an "test.xml" next to the build.xml. How can I modified the codes above so that I can pass the "test.xml" into the subbuild.xml and do some operations in the subbuild.xml?

Actually, I want to pass the "test.xml" as a  of a  task in subbuild.xml. I am just confused about how to let the subbuild.xml get accessed to the "test.xml" in the build.xml. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set a property containing the name of the file in your `build.xml` before calling the `subbuild.xml`. An Ant subproject invoked using the `ant` task automatically inherits all properties set in their parent unless the attribute `inheritAll` is set to false. Alternatively you can pass the property to the subproject with a nested `property` element as suggested by CAustin in the comments.

**First method:**

```
<target name="antCall1" >
    <!-- since the file is in the same directory as the build.xml -->
    <property name="input.file" value="test.xml" />
    <ant antfile="${basedir}/cache/subBuildTarget/subbuild.xml" />
</target>
```

**Second method:**

```
<target name="antCall1" >
    <ant antfile="${basedir}/cache/subBuildTarget/subbuild.xml">
        <property name="input.file" value="test.xml" />
    </ant>
</target>
```

In `subbuild.xml`:

```
<loadfile property="file.contents" srcFile="${input.file}"/>
<echo message="${file.contents}" />
```

Comment: It would probably be more appropriate to pass `input.file` as a nested property of the `ant` task.  That way subbuild.xml could be called multiple times with a different file specified as the input, if necessary.

Comment: @CAustin Yes it's another alternative. I included it as well. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What if I want to load a String? is there a <loadString> tag in ant?

Comment: There is no concept of a "String" in Ant in the sense of a standard programming language. If you mean a property that contains some text, then you can access the property using `${property.name}`

Comment: @diCoder The above `<echo message="${file.contents}" />` is a perfect example. It prints out to the console the value of the property `file.contents` which holds the contents of `test.xml`.

Comment: I want to get the absolute path of the "test.xml", so that I can use this path as a 'arg' value of a 'java' target in the 'subbuild.xml'. How can I do that?@manouti

Comment: @diCoder Kindly ask another question or look up if it's already asked.